# Flutter Make showDateRangePicker Smaller

Tags: flutter, dart

Following Flutter's documentation for [showDateRangePicker](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDateRangePicker.html) creates a full-screen picker. This seems fine on mobile, but on iPad and web, it's obnoxious.

I need a way to constrain the proportions to make the overlay smaller.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding the `builder` parameter to the `showDateRangePicker()` function will allow you to place the date range picker inside a container or constrained box.

Keep in mind, this only seems to work when the parent widget of the builder is a **Column**.

**Example:**

```
dateTimeRangePicker() async {
      DateTimeRange picked = await showDateRangePicker(
          context: context,
          firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 5),
          lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 5),
          initialDateRange: DateTimeRange(
            end: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day + 13),
            start: DateTime.now(),
          ),
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                ConstrainedBox(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxWidth: 400.0,
                  ),
                  child: child,
                )
              ],
            );
          });
      print(picked);
    }
```

The `ConstrainedBox` widget allows us to specify maxWidth and maxHeight properties. This allows us to still see a full-screen display on smaller devices where it makes sense, but to limit the max size on larger devices like an iPad or web browser.

In my opinion, this widget looks great tall, because it shows many months you can scroll through. However, it does not look great wide.

The above example shows a `maxWidth` constraint only. But `maxHeight` could also be added if you wanted to limit that too.

With these constraints, the picker shows as an overlay, where the background is dimmed. You can click anywhere on the background to close the overlay, to cancel the selection and return **null**.

Comment: Just to add - you can use Center and Align instead of Column like so
```
Center(
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
       maxWidth: 400.0,  
       maxHeight: 600.0,
     ),
   child: child,
  ),
);
```

Comment: I cant achieve this with NULL SAFETY i get............, error: The argument type 'Theme Function(BuildContext, Widget)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget?)?'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [ovaloop] lib/screens/dashboard/order/orderScreen.dart:57)